# Can't write to CSV in function

Tags: python

This will return the exception "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file"

```
def clear():
    os.system('cls')
def openFile(operation):
    global file
    global writer
    with open(r'C:\\Users\\User\Documents\\Proxy Database\\Proxy.csv',operation, newline= '') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
while True:
    dir = input('Enter Operation > ')
    if dir == 'add':
        openFile("a")
        print('! Adding User !')
        name = input('Enter Name > ')
        writer.writerow([name])
        print('User Added')
        file.flush()
        clear()
        continue
```

I notice that when I put all the code under the initial CSV Open everything works fine, it just dosen't work when put into a function.

```
with open(r'C:\\Users\\ricco\Documents\\Proxy Database\\Proxy.csv','r+', newline= '') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        while True:
            dir = input('Enter Operation > ')
            if dir == 'add':
                print('! Adding User !')
                name = input('Enter Name > ')
                writer.writerow([name])
                print('User Added')
                file.flush()
                break
        print('Done')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what would be an answer to this question since you seem to have already figured out what the problem is and found a way to avoid it. You can just put the last code into a function, though.

Comment: Read up about context managers. As soon as you leave the context (i.e. the indented block directly below the `with` statement), the context (and the file) is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work, because you did *not* put all of the pertinent code into the function.
You open the file in a `with` block inside your function.  Then you exit the block (which closes the file), return from the function, and then your main program attempts to write to the closed file ... hence the error message.

If you want to open the file in the function, but write to it in the calling routine, then you need a normal `open`, and have the function return the needed information.  For instance:

```
def openFile(operation):

    handle = open(r'C:\\Users\\User\Documents\\Proxy Database\\Proxy.csv',operation, newline= '')
    writer = csv.writer(handle)
    return writer

...
writer = openFile("a")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```py
> with open(r'C:\\Users\\User\Documents\\Proxy Database\\Proxy.csv',operation, newline= '') as file:
>     writer = csv.writer(file)
> ```

What would you do if there were no `with` keyword ? You would write above like this:

```py
file = open(r'C:\\Users\\User\Documents\\Proxy Database\\Proxy.csv',operation, newline='')
writer = csv.writer(file)
file.close()
```

You have seen right : the with statement closes the file at the end (here after the **global** writer object is created), and so any further I/O operations will fail. In this case you should drop the with keyword and create a file object normally.

```py
file = open(r'C:\\Users\\User\Documents\\Proxy Database\\Proxy.csv',operation, newline='')
writer = csv.writer(file)
```

But at the end of your code, you then should add `file.close()` to make sure it is closed !

[`with` keyword docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)